# I have an array of multiple objects. Can we create new object based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
var arrNewMarket=[];
var arrMarket=[
{id:1,country:"India",city:"city1",fruit:"Red Apple",year:2019,jan:220,feb:300},
{id:2,country:"India",city:"city1",fruit:"Green Apple",year:2019,jan:777,feb:555},
  {id:3,country:"India",city:"city2",fruit:"Red Apple",year:2019,jan:333,feb:888},
]
console.log(arrMarket);

for (let i = 0; i < arrMarket.length-1; i++) {
  for (let j = i+1; j < arrMarket.length; j++) 
  { 
    if(arrMarket[i].country==arrMarket[j].country && arrMarket[i].city==arrMarket[j].city) {
       arrNewMarket.push({
         id:4,
         country:arrMarket[i].country,
         city:arrMarket[i].city,
         fruit:"Apple",
         year:arrMarket[i].year,
         jan:arrMarket[i].jan/arrMarket[j].jan,
         feb:arrMarket[i].feb/arrMarket[j].feb,
       });
     }
  }
}
```

I have an array of multiple objects.

```
var arrMarket=[];
[
{id:1,country:India,city:city1,year:2019,jan:220,feb:300},
{id:2,country:India,city:city1,year:2019,jan:777,feb:555},
]
```

Can we create new object based on conditions 
for eg:
   if **country matches** and **city matches** then some "Divide" calculation for Jan and Feb and we can have 3rd object?

Any Suggestion and help will be appreciated.

```
[
    {id:1,country:India,city:city1,year:2019,jan:220,feb:300},
    {id:2,country:India,city:city1,year:2019,jan:777,feb:555},
 {id:3,country:India,city:city1,year:2019,jan:0.28,feb:0.54},
    ]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please elaborate more on what operation are you trying to perform on object and what should be the expected output?

Comment: Yes, surely it is possible, but putting that new object in the same array doesn't really make sense. Also, what if there are more than two objects with the same country and city in the input - you can't divide them? And how do you know which one should become divisor and which dividend?

Comment: @Bergi is it possible to get that new object in new array?

Comment: @Learner Yes, that's possible as well. Have you tried it?

Comment: Use nested loops that go through the array twice. When the country and city match, then do the calculations and push the result in another array.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arrMarket.length-1; i++) for (let j = i+1; j < arrMarket.length; j++) { code that compares arrMarket[i] with arrMarket[j] }`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I tried something but it is not pushing the new value to new Array.

Comment: It works. Put `console.log(arrNewMarket)` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Thank you. Just want to ask one thing. Will it always divide (Red Apple/Green Apple) object ?

Comment: It will divide them in the order that they're in the array. It divides the first one by the second.

Comment: You can add code to check the `arrMarket[i].fruit` and order the division appropriately.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for asking again but how could arrMarket[i].fruit will order the division as per our need.?

Comment: `if (arrMarket[i].fruit == "Red Apple") { ... } else { ... }`. The first block divides i by j, the second divides j by i.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lodash filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter).

It will allow you to pick out all of the objects in the array that meet the condition.

```
import filter from 'lodash/filter'

const array = [
        {id:1,country: "India", city:"city1", year:2019, jan:220, feb:300},
        {id:2,country: "India", city:"city1", year:2019, jan:777, feb:555},
        {id:3,country: "UK", city:"city2", year:2019, jan:1, feb:12},
     ]

// gives you a list of all objects that match you conditions.
const filteredArray = filter(array, {country: "India", city: "city1"}) 

// make a new object with whatever math you wanted to do.
const newObject = {id: array.length, country: "India", city: "city1", year: 2019, jan: filteredArray.map(**some calculation**),feb: filteredArray.map(**some calculation**)}

// to ad it back to the original array of objects
array.push(newObject)
```

Hope that gives you somewhere to start.